# Remove br tags from CKEditor output

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I made a CMS and I'm working with posts which were written by Wordpress CMS.  I want to save my new content in a way which WordPress did. Actually, WordPress purified the written text a little. It doesn't escape `br` tags.

Look at this example text (saved by Wordpress):

```
<span style="color: #0000ff;">Hi.I'm Peter</span>
Its a new line with one Enter key
&nbsp;
Its another line after two Enter key
```

Image of saved text in database

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't escape any `br` tags for new lines.

I used `config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;` to get rid of automatic `P` tag insertion but now it inserts `br` for new lines and makes the above example text like this one:

```html
<span style="color:#0000ff">Hi. I'm Peter</span><br />
Its a new line with one Enter key<br />
<br />
Its another line after two Enter key
```

Image oftext saved by cms and ckeditor
[image]

So, I have 2 questions:

1- How can I extract my content exactly like the first example ?

2- I also have problem with showing first example based content in CKeditor and it add `br` tag for new lines by itself and make text ruined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post text, not images. Not everyone can see images.

Comment: @RobG The images say the exact same as the text in the code boxes....

Comment: @Jamin—cool, but I don't know that because I can't see the images…

Comment: if you dont have the br's the text will be collapsed to one line by any browser.

Comment: @nogad Just concentrate on my question. I don't have problem with showing them in my template ( I use a function to turn those empty lines into p tags).

Comment: if you don't want HTML output, don't use an editor that writes HTML, just use a textarea.

Comment: Replace `<br />` before saving: `EDITORINSTANCE.getData().replace(/<br \/>/gi, '&nbsp;')`